# How to do a join on a inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have this database:

`table`

```
id  fname       dphone      count_pic   dup_id  

6055903 Karla       5126xxx798  1       57  
6173767 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  4       39  
5611411 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  15      39  
5611211 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  18      39  
4234798 Abby        3057xxx974  31      16  
6166691 Walter      6178xxx280  1       74  
3375576 Walter      6178xxx280  17      74
```

and I found out how to do an inner join on it like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(count_pic) AS minpic,
               MAX(count_pic) AS maxpic,
               dup_id
          FROM table
      GROUP BY dup_id) t2 ON t1.dup_id = t2.dup_id
                         AND (t1.count_pic = minpic
                           OR t1.count_pic = maxpic)
```

but what if I want to join this table with another one based on `id` and return some values , like `date,`from the second table as well:

`table2`

```
    id  date

6055903 111111111
6173767 111111111
5611411 111111111
```

Any ideas on this?

edit:

the inner join is fine the way it is, i need to add the `table2` on top of that query

Comment: Just add a second join? `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON(table1.id = table2.foreign_id) JOIN table3 ON(table1.id = table3.foreign_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `JOIN` at the end:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(count_pic) AS minpic,
               MAX(count_pic) AS maxpic,
               dup_id
          FROM table
      GROUP BY dup_id) t2 ON t1.dup_id = t2.dup_id
                         AND (t1.count_pic = minpic
                           OR t1.count_pic = maxpic)

INNER JOIN table2 ON t1.id = table2.id -- add this
```